# How to update latest notification in android app?

Tags: android, json, servlets, webview

I made an app for an institution in which i have to update it with latest news and latest notifications.

One way I use is the **web view**, I linked my app with the website **url** and when i update my website it will work,

But I want an another solution of it without using webview.

How is it possible by using servlet and JSON ?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use json , create simple web service to access website posts.
if your website have `rss` you can use it.
[Android RSS Reader Application](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/android-rss-reader-application-using-sqlite-part-1/)